# Detect the device is shutting down?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, device

In my android application i need to do some action if the device is turning off suddenly. Is there any  way to detect the device is shutting down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Broadcast Action: Device is shutting down. This is broadcast when the
>   device is being shut down (completely turned off, not sleeping). Once
>   the broadcast is complete, the final shutdown will proceed and all
>   unsaved data lost. Apps will not normally need to handle this, since
>   the foreground activity will be paused as well.
>
> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

**May include the following extras:**

> ```
> EXTRA_SHUTDOWN_USERSPACE_ONLY a boolean that is set to true if this shutdown is only for userspace processes. If not set, assumed to be false.
> ```

**Constant Value:** `"android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"`

[Intent | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN).

[You have to configure the broadcast receiver to listen for this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).