# check if phone is shutting down in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

In Android there is a broadcast for SHUTTING_DOWN.
[Detect the device is shutting down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514698/detect-the-device-is-shutting-down)

In iOS is there any way to find out if the phone is shutting down?

Comment: Why would you need that, given your app is probably in the background anyway?

Comment: depending on this information, i need to reset significant location changes.

Comment: I still don't follow.  When the app is back in the foreground (regardless of what's happened to the phone between the last time), can't you get the location and compare it against the last location and then make decisions based on distance etc?

Comment: @trojanfoe: if it is shutting down, if have to enable significant location changes else disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not such thing, because apps in iOS are all located in sandbox, meaning that they are isolated from the iOS like in a nutshell. You can only get info from the "outer world" through the AppDelegate methods, but the call you are looking for is not provided there, which is too system-specific.